# Why core_write is not working on sales_flat_quote_item in Magento CE 1.9.1

Tags: php, magento

I am newly started working With Magento CE 1.9.1.0

Here i wants to override Magento **addAction()** for that i have added some code in my custom module like this.

**config.xml :**

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Naresh_Customcheckout before="Mage_Checkout">Naresh_Customcheckout</Naresh_Customcheckout>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

**CartController.php :**

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class Naresh_Customcheckout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController {
    public function addAction(){
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }
        $cart   = $this->_getCart();
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            /**
             * Check product availability
             */
            if (!$product) {
                $this->_goBack();
                return;
            }

            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }

            $cart->save();

            $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

            $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
            $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
            if ($params['new_cusom_options'] == 'add_new_gift') {
                $quote_id1 = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getId();
                $custom_weight = 0.600; // Its dynamic Value from DB 
                $query2 = "UPDATE  sales_flat_quote_item SET `weight` = `weight` + ".$custom_weight.", `row_weight` = `row_weight` + ".$custom_weight." WHERE `quote_id` = ".$quote_id1." AND `product_id` = ".$params['product'];
                $write->query($query2);
            }

            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
             */
            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
            );

            if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                    $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
                }
                $this->_goBack();
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->_getSession()->addNotice(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($message));
                }
            }

            $url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
            if ($url) {
                $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            } else {
                $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_goBack();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

In Cart controller i want to add extra weight to weight and row_weight for the product.

And i tried to see the Database values before and after update query the results are like this.

```
$query1 = "SELECT `weight`, `row_weight` FROM `sales_flat_quote_item` WHERE `quote_id` = ".$cart_id." AND `product_id` = ".$_product->getId();
Mage::log($query1);
$results = $read->fetchAll($query1);
Mage::log($results[0]);

$query2 = "UPDATE  sales_flat_quote_item SET `weight` = `weight` + ".$custom_weight.", `row_weight` = `row_weight` + ".$custom_weight." WHERE `quote_id` = ".$cart_id." AND `product_id` = ".$_product->getId();
Mage::log($query2);
$write->query($query2);

$query3 = "SELECT `weight`, `row_weight` FROM `sales_flat_quote_item` WHERE `quote_id` = ".$cart_id." AND `product_id` = ".$_product->getId();
Mage::log($query3);
$results1 = $read->fetchAll($query3);
Mage::log($results1[0]);
```

**system.log**

```
2015-07-23T06:00:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): SELECT `weight`, `row_weight` FROM `sales_flat_quote_item` WHERE `quote_id` = 21 AND `product_id` = 1
2015-07-23T06:00:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [weight] => 0.5600
    [row_weight] => 0.5600
)

2015-07-23T06:00:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): UPDATE  sales_flat_quote_item SET `weight` = `weight` + 0.6, `row_weight` = `row_weight` + 0.6 WHERE `quote_id` = 21 AND `product_id` = 1
2015-07-23T06:00:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): SELECT `weight`, `row_weight` FROM `sales_flat_quote_item` WHERE `quote_id` = 21 AND `product_id` = 1
2015-07-23T06:00:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [weight] => 1.1600
    [row_weight] => 1.1600
)
```

as per Query3 i can see the values has been updated successfully but in Database the values are like this

[image]

Because of that query my database value is not getting updated why it is happening ?

I hope nothing is wrong in the above lines.

I am not getting why it is happening like this.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Please check first quote id in sales_flat_quote_item table

Comment: @user3793635 there is no problem with quote id, I am getting that from the following code  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getId(); and i have checked it several times

Comment: print query resulut by Zend_Debug::dump($results); and see the result.

Comment: Yes i tried with log files here is the details 2015-07-22T12:14:19+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
)

Comment: @user3793635 Now its working fine i just tried after flushing the Cache. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: It means quote_id value null so please pass static values of quote_id from sales_flat_quote_item table and check.

Comment: @user3793635 $quote_id is not null, every time  am printing that in log files and i can see that Id in my Log file

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You had not enclosed the `$quote_id` variable properly

```
$query1 = 'SELECT * FROM sales_flat_quote_item WHERE quote_id = "'.$quote_id.'"';
```

Comment: Now its working fine i just tried after flushing the Cache. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: are you sure the code inside `if ($params['new_cusom_options'] == 'add_new_gift')` is executed. ?

Comment: Yes there is no problem with if ($params['new_cusom_options'] == 'add_new_gift') and i tried for this 100s of times